# twitterizer tweet favorite count

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

```
    TwitterStatusCollection tweets = 
TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(oauth,options).ResponseObject;
```

With twitterizer UserTimeline function we can get all info about tweet except for tweet favorite(like) count.How can I get tweet favorite(like) count with twitterizer?

Comment: As described here: http://yazilimsozluk.com/twitterizer-tweet-favorite-count  we should add favorite count property to response class model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described here: yazilimsozluk.com/twitterizer-tweet-favorite-count we should add favorite count property to response class model